# php in two way encryption algorithms how is encrypted data shorter than input data?

Tags: php, encryption

I created encryption method for encryp,decrypt important data .
sample of my encryption method :

```
$str='some important text'; // 19 
// encrypted $str : 'A6oLM5{!lr4Y9xON4-55Tty%>6A4vgU^893cGv)g' // 40
```

as you see length of input is 19 and output is 40

I found some two way encryption methods that encrypted data shorter than input data .

how that is possible ?

Comment: it's better to provide an example for better explanation

Comment: And which "encryption" methods would that be? Perhaps they aren't actually encryption, or at least not exclusively so (e.g. encryption + compression).

Comment: You did it backwards?? No idea. You're probably just thinking about it wrong. Hard to say without seeing more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect also that you considered some hashing algorithms such as md5, sha, etc that provides fixed length of result for any given data.

Another possibilities is compression, for example:

I compressed this using this site: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/compress/

```
1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777
888888888899999999990000000000
```

The result was:

```
eNo9wbEBABAMALCXlFL+f8zUJBFtskg2h+LyGHz9kBSD
```

Answer (score 2):

You've not said (or shown us) what your encryption algorithm is. Nor have you provided an example to support your question (the example you provided shows the opposite)

The short answer is that it isn't shorter - it's impossible for the encrypted data to be smaller than the source data - any good encryption algorithm does not simply substitute individual characters but generates output based on the sequence of inputs. Typically it's a multiple of the key size and greater than the input.

That you seem to be seeing a shorter output is due to the input being compressed before it is encrypted.